# Is there a Compatibility Mode for iOS Safari I can set?

Tags: safari, ios, http

I have an IIS hosted website.  With iOS 8, some of the page looks ugly now in Safari.  Until we have the resources to determine what's wrong so we can fix the website, I was hoping I can set an HTTP Response Header to set "compatibility mode" somehow in Safari?

For example, for IE, there's the X-UA-Compatibility header that you can set to say "always render as IE9" if needed.  I'm looking for something similar, to tell Safari to always render as whatever Safari in iOS 7 is.

Comment: No such mode exists for Safari. IE's compatibility mode is basically a band-aid for developers who coded around...oddities in prior versions of IE in ways that would break rendering when newer, more standards-compliant versions of IE are introduced.